# Is it possible to save a form value into a local file with Angular 2?

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to save a form builder value into a JSON local file. Is that possible with angular 2 or should I try using some third part to get it done?

Comment: define "local file" ..

Answer (score 0):

Not,  It's a violation of the sandbox.
It has nothing to do with angular it self.
Read more: [javascript security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security)